# Issue in creating a Foreign Key relationship through Hibernate Annonations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 class Employee and Passport, then I tried to create a one to one mapping with Primary and Foreign Key Relationship with Annotations, but the foreign key relationship is not happening in Passport table.

Here Primary_Id is Emp_No in Employee table and must be a foreign Key in Passport table.

Below i have provided the 2 POJO classes for Employee and Passport and also the generated SQL from Hibernate.

Could somebody help me where I make mistake. Kindly let me know in case of further information.

**Employee**

```
package com.otr.hibernate;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 *
 * @author SPAR
 */
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String emp_No;
    private String first_Name;
    private String second_Name;
    private String designation;


    public String getEmp_No() {
        return emp_No;
    }

    public void setEmp_No(String emp_No) {
        this.emp_No = emp_No;
    }

    public String getFirst_Name() {
        return first_Name;
    }

    public void setFirst_Name(String first_Name) {
        this.first_Name = first_Name;
    }

    public String getSecond_Name() {
        return second_Name;
    }

    public void setSecond_Name(String second_Name) {
        this.second_Name = second_Name;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

}
```

**Passport.java**

```
package com.otr.hibernate;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;

/**
 *
 * @author SPAR
 */
@Entity
public class Passport implements Serializable {

    private String passport_No;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "foreign")
    @GenericGenerator(name= "foreign", strategy = "foreign", parameters = {@Parameter(value = "employee", name = "property")})
    private String emp_RN_No;

    @OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "emp_RN_No")
    private Employee employee;


   public String getPassport_No() {
        return passport_No;
    }

    public void setPassport_No(String passport_No) {
        this.passport_No = passport_No;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

     public String getEmp_No() {
        return emp_No;
    }

    public void setEmp_RN_No(String emp_No) {
        this.emp_No = emp_No;
    }

}
```

Hibernate Generation

```
Hibernate: create table Employee (emp_No varchar(255) not null, designation varchar(255), first_Name varchar(255), second_Name varchar(255), primary key (emp_No));

Hibernate: create table Passport (emp_No varchar(255) not null, passport_No varchar(255), primary key (emp_No));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the GenericGenerator to do that. There are two simpler alternatives:

1. Combine @Id and @OneToOne:

   ```
   @Id @OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "emp_RN_No")
   private Employee employee;
   ```

   Make sure you remove the previous @Id property `emp_RN_No`
2. Using @MapsId:

   ```
   @Id
   private String emp_RN_No;

   @MapsId @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "emp_RN_No")
   private Employee employee;
   ```

Comment: Thanks the problem solved, I have used the first choice, Can i know the difference the 2 option

Comment: The [@MapsId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) is supported by JPA. The first one is Hibernate specific.